# Pattern matching not matching given variable

Tags: scala, pascals-triangle

I have made an implementation of the pascal's triangle but something is wrong with it since when `col match { case row => ...}` it doesn't correctly match the col with the row:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
println("Pascal's Triangle")
for (row <- 0 to 10) {
  for (col <- 0 to row) {
    val res: Int = pascal(col, row)
    print(res + " ")
  }
  println()
}

def pascal(col: Int, row: Int): Int = {
    col match {
      case 0 => 1
      case row => 1
      case _ => pascal(col-1, row-1) + pascal(col, row-1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `row` match is shadowing the method parameter. To achieve what you want, you could try to use so called guards for your pattern match, e.g.

```
case n if n == row => 1
```

With this, you have 3 cases, the `0` case, the case when `n is equal to given row parameter` and the `default` case. Otherwise, the `row` match would match all remaining numbers not equal to `0`, which will leave the `_` match at the end never be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to Martin's answer, you can also use backticks for the same result:

```
def pascal(col: Int, row: Int): Int = {
  col match {
    case 0 => 1
    case `row` => 1
    case _ => pascal(col-1, row-1) + pascal(col, row-1)
  }
}
```

You can read more on this behaviour in, e.g., related chapter of the [*Programming in Scala* book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-scala-2nd/9781491950135/ch04.html) (search for the *backticks* keyword)